# Java Operator Precedence Expression Evaluation

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I have the following variable decelrations, assignments and variable declerations

variable e is an expression statement which should return the value of the evaulated variables in the expression;

What is the order of precdence of the opperators in the e variable?

Computed it equals = 60;

With a calculator I get 422;

```
int a, b, c, d;

a = 10;
b = 2;
c = 1;
d = 20;

e = a + b * d / c + a + b / d;


e = 10 + 2 * 20 / 1 + 10 + 2 / 20;

e = 60;
```

Comment: http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php

Comment: I fail to see how you could get 422 on a calculator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the answer is `60.1` but since `variables` are int its showing `60`. It is happening as below

```
10 + (2 * (20 / 1)) + 10 + (int)(2 / 20) = 10 + (2 * 20) + 10 + (int)0.1
= 10 + 40 + 10 + 0 = 60
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) outlining operator precedence.  As for your result, this can also be attributed to integer division (which takes the floor of the result; for instance, `2/20 = 0`).

Answer (score 0):

Just like in school, multiplication and division have priority over addition. So you have:

```
10 + 2 * 20 / 1 + 10 + 2 / 20 = 10 + 40 + 10 + 0 = 60
```

Answer (score 0):

```
* takes first precedence so first, 2*20 =40,  10 + 40 / 1 + 10 + 2 / 20;
/ takes precedence so ,  10 + 40 + 10 + 0;
+ takes precedence so, 60
```

Here is link for operator precedence:  [Operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)